# Compound Inequalities: help understanding AND & OR

Tags: inequality

Been getting back into math and can't seem to wrap my head around how compound inequalities work. Here is an example problem from Khan Academy[AND]I understand how to solve the inequality, but don't know how to get to the solution or lack of one I do not get.

if image isn't showing I have provided the question

solve for x

5x-4≥12 AND 12x+5≤-4

Comment: Solve each then take the intersection of the two sets of solutions (and) or their union (or)

Comment: How do you simultaneously understand how to solve the inequality without understanding how to reach the solution? That makes no sense lol. In any case, your first inequality leads to $x$ being greater than or equal to some quantity (call it $y$), while the second leads to $x$ being less than or equal to some other quantity (call it $z$). So the answer is simply $y\le x \le z$

Comment: Evidently you have a partial understanding of what to do, and it's hard for us to tell exactly where it is that you got stuck or went wrong. Try showing all your work on the problem, explaining what you were thinking about each step.

Comment: $x\ge16/5\text{ and }x\le-3/4$. Try plotting these and see where they intersect.